# Why does a JS script placed after the </body> and </header> get executed?

Tags: javascript, html, behavior, execution

I was working on something in PHP and I wanted to include a file and insert something at the end. Without thinking about it, I did the include and then echoed out the material I wanted to insert, which was a JS script.

When I looked at the output, I realized I had forgotten about the  tags in the included file. The script was inserted after them, but surprisingly (at least to me) it was executed.

Had you asked me before I did this if a script after the  and  tags would execute, I would have said "I don't think so." I would have said that I thought it would not execute because I had assumed, up to now that anything after the  and  tags is ignored by browsers.

So, had you asked, I would have given that answer and I would have been quite wrong.

A script placed after the  and  tags does execute - why?

I've tried it with FF 3.6.24 and I.E 8.0.7601.17514 and it behaves the same in both.

Any text after the  and  tags is displayed - why?

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? And, is this something I might be able to rely upon? If so, I can simplify some processing, here and there.

Here's the page I was playing with http://www.bobnovell.com/PastHtmlEndTesting.shtml - let me know if your particular browser does not execute the script and/or display the text that I've put after the script.

Bob

Comment: The browser will parse the entire file, not just where the tags are.

Answer (score 5):

This is well specified behavior in HTML5 though it will be flagged by an HTML5 validator.

The [after after body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tree-construction.html#the-after-after-body-insertion-mode) insertion mode defines what happens to content that is after the `</html>` tag.  The rule that handles this case is:

> **Anything else**
>
> > ↪ Parse error. Switch the insertion mode to ["in body"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inbody) and reprocess the token.

So techinically, it's a parse error, but one with well defined behavior.  The `<script>` element is parsed and executed as if it had appeared in the body, and the element should appear in the DOM in the body.

Most browsers will not treat "parse errors" as fatal.  The [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parse-error) explains:

> Certain points in the parsing algorithm are said to be parse errors. **The error handling for parse errors is well-defined**: user agents must either act as described below when encountering such problems, or must abort processing at the first error that they encounter for which they do not wish to apply the rules described below.